# Create another Table in data base or use xml?

Tags: php, xml, database

I'm developing a data base driven web application. but I now I got a dilemma .
My data consists of names and their cods. The codes are data base table field names.
I need to display name of corresponding code. same name may contain deferent codes.

should I create another data base table or use xml ?

Comment: please can you tell me what's wrong wit that? I will edit my question.

Comment: @Sagar: the problem with this type of question is that there is not a single "right" answer. It will likely lead to debate between proponents of various solutions. Although such debate can be very good and very welcome, Stack Overflow is not the correct site for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This surely depends on how much entries you have to handle and how often the data will change.
Is it easier to you to exchange the xml-file or to update the database?

But as if the database is already present i would propose to use it. You don't have to deal with persistency and such things if using the database.

But nevertheless it is an endless conflict of what to use. Both ways work. Both have advantages and disadvantages.